# How to do IP Canonicalization Test in .htaccess file

Tags: seo

How to do IP Canonicalization for my website. 
I have tried some like this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^00.009.198.252
but its not working.
Please help me

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.freelancerabraham.com/$1 [R=301,L]

url of my website- www.freelancerabraham.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using appache you can change 'allow from all' to "allow from 'YOUR HOST'"